# linecache.getline() returns nothing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function to put inside the `except` part of `try` and I want it to log error info. The problem is I can not get code line which produced the error as I could do it before. look at this code:

```
def func():
    try:
        a = 1
        b = 0
        print a / b
    except:
        Debug.log()
```

And this is log function:

```
def log(cls):
    try:
        exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
        f = tb.tb_frame
        line_no = str(tb.tb_lineno)
        filename = f.f_code.co_filename
        linecache.checkcache(filename)
        line = linecache.getline(filename, line_no, f.f_globals)
        current_frame = inspect.currentframe()
        previous_frame = current_frame.f_back
        func_name = previous_frame.f_code.co_name
        msg = str(exc_obj)

        obj = Error()
        obj.filename = filename
        obj.line_no = line_no
        obj.line = line
        obj.msg = msg
        obj.function = func_name
        obj.save()
```

After execution I can see the line is empty:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5413d67a65765f16219aa575"),
    "filename" : "E:/Developer Center/DomainServices/DomainServices/test.py",
    "line_no" : "23",
    "line" : "",
    "msg" : "integer division or modulo by zero",
    "function" : "func",
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is passing a `str` object to `linecache.getline`.

```
line_no = str(tb.tb_lineno)
          ^^^
```

According to [`linecache.py` source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/301c672ceca6/Lib/linecache.py#l13), the passed line number is compared to 1 and total number of line:

```
    if 1 <= lineno <= len(lines):
        return lines[lineno-1]
    else:
        return ''
```

Because the `lineno` is `str` object, the predicated is evaluated as `False` in Python 2.x (raise an exception in Python 3.x because comparison between `str` and `int` is not allowed)

```
>>> 1 < '2' < 3
False
```

You get an empty string.

---

You should pass an `int` object.

```
line = linecache.getline(filename, int(line_no))
```

or

```
line = linecache.getline(filename, tb.tb_lineno)
```